# Is there any workaround to reduce the size of the embedded fonts in Haxe OpenFL?

Tags: haxe, openfl

Is there any workaround to reduce the size of the embedded fonts in Haxe OpenFL?

After adding web formats, it's taking too much space. I am targeting HTML5.

[image: Check this image]

I always use `-final` to reduce the size of the `.js` file:

```
openfl test html5 -final -v
```

But it’s still a drawback to have these Mbs. Is there any way to load the fonts from another place without embedding them to reduce the overall size of the project?

Or maybe I am thinking wrong? It is the only way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple random thoughts:

That's a lot of faces, thicknesses (500/700/900), and styles (italic, regular). Are you using them all? You could consider paring down to only ones you really need.

However, any given browser should only load the format it requires (woff/eot/ttf/svg, [info here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp)), so any given user shouldn't download the whole 2.43MB set. Try looking at the network panel in Chrome dev tools to see what a Chrome user loads (or similarly in IE, or Safari.)

Comment: yes you are right i just noticed it is only taking in bits so no worries at all :)